# Homework-Second derivative of a multivariate function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Let $f(x):\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and let $\theta(\alpha)=f(x+\alpha s)$ where $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x,s\in\mathbb{R}^n$, the goal is to find $\theta''(\alpha)$. I guess that the answer should be $s^TH(x+\alpha s)s$ where $H(x)$ is the Hessian matrix of $f(x)$. I try to use the chain rule, but I don't see what is wrong in the following calculation:
$$\theta''(\alpha)=[f(x+\alpha s)]''=[f'(x+\alpha s)s]'=f''(x+\alpha s)ss=H(x+\alpha s)ss$$